# Triangulating Polyhedron faces in CGAL

Tags: cgal

Having an arbitrary polyhedron in CGAL (one that can be convex, concave or, even, have holes) how can I triangulate its faces so that I can create OpenGL Buffers for rendering?

I have seen the convex_hull_3() returns a polyhedron that has triangulated faces, but it won't do what I want for arbitrary polyhedrons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The header file `<CGAL/triangulate_polyhedron.h>` contains a non-documented function

```
template <typename Polyhedron>
void triangulate_polyhedron(Polyhedron& p)
```

that is working with `CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel` for example.

Comment: My project's working with Simple_cartesian<float> kernel. Is there a way I can use that function with this kernel? Sorry, I'm new to CGAL...

Comment: You can try, but there is no guarantee on the result. See http://www.cgal.org/FAQ.html#inexact_NT.

Comment: What can I do to convert from a polyhedron with a Simple_cartesian to one with Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel?

Comment: You just need to change the kernel and that should work.

Comment: FYI: this header has since been removed from the CGAL project. A new package for triangulations has been introduced: http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation/index.html

Comment: @scry: Note that you should use this package in case you have a dimension greater than 3. For dimension 2 and 3, dimension dedicated packages are more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

The *Polygon Mesh Processing* package provides the function `CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::triangulate_faces` with multiple overloads. The simplest thing to do would be

```
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<float> Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel> Polyhedron_3;

Polyhedron_3 polyhedron = load_my_polyhedron();
CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::triangulate_faces(polyhedron);
```

After that, all faces in `polyhedron` are triangles.

The function modifies the model in-place, so one has to use a `HalfedgeDS` that supports removal. This is the default, but, for example, `HalfedgeDS_vector` won't do.

See also an official example that uses `Surface_mesh` instead of `Polyhedron_3`:
 [Polygon_mesh_processing/triangulate_faces_example.cpp](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/Polygon_mesh_processing_2triangulate_faces_example_8cpp-example.html#a4)